# How to pass grandparent object to call parent method

Tags: java, inheritance

```
Class A {

}

Class B extends A {
    public void aMethod(A a){

    }
}

class C extends B {

    aMethod()          /* What argument should i pass in here? I 
        cannot change class A  and Class B */

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to override `aMethod()` in `C`? If so, you don't have a choice but to make it take `A`.

Comment: No I am not trying to override but calling the method of parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both C and B and extending class A, in that case you can pass to `aMethod` an instance of class A, B, or C

Answer (score 1):

since both B and c extends A, you can pass instance of A,B or C to the Object which refers A.

```
    class A {

}

class B extends A {
    public void aMethod(A a){
System.out.println(a.getClass());
    }
}

class C extends B {

   public static void main(String[] ar){
       new C().aMethod(new A()) ;
       new C().aMethod(new B()) ;
       new C().aMethod(new C()) ;

   }      /* C has IS a relationship with both A , B and C */

}
```

you can assign a child class object to parent class object.

`Parent p = new Child();`
here child class is Both B and  C.
parent is A

the output of the above code is :
`class collections.A
class collections.B
class collections.C`

> if the question you are asking about overriding .there is only one method hence it doesnt override anything. and passing an object as parameter has nothing to do with calling a method . a method gets called based on its runtime object, hence to really answer you question you would call `new B().aMethod(new A()) ;` *this calls B class method using granparent object as parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are invoking the method aMethod(), you can pass an instance of class A, B or C as all of these classes inherit class A directly or indirectly.

But if you want to override the method aMethod() then you would have to pass the same type of argument as the method defined in class B, as overriding means (as explained in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) ) -

"An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method."

```
    Class C extends B {
       public void aMethod(A a){
          //Method Definition here
       }
    }
```